# Convert serialized data to array or object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, serialization

I have a string like this:

`(redMultiplier=0, greenMultiplier=0, blueMultiplier=0, alphaMultiplier=1, redOffset=0, greenOffset=102, blueOffset=51, alphaOffset=0)`

I need to convert this string to array (or object). And I have a lot of strings like this to convert to array too. Is there any way to automatically convert a string like this to javascript array?

Comment: Can you show the expected output? What would the array look like?

Comment: The output can be a object like this: `{redMultiplier:0, greenMultiplier:0 ... };`, because if I'm not wrong, named array indexes doesn't work in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this function will return a object when you transmit a string as it's parameter:

```
function convert(str){
    str = str.replace(/\(|\)/g,'');
    var arr = str.split(',');
    var obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var singleArr = arr[i].trim().split('=');
      var name = singleArr[0];
      var value = singleArr[1]-0;
      if (obj[name] == undefined) {
        obj[name] = value;
      }
    }
    return obj;
  }
```

the obj like Object {redMultiplier: 0, greenMultiplier: 0, blueMultiplier: 0, alphaMultiplier: 1}

Answer (score 2):

You can use RegExp.

```
var str = '(redMultiplier=0, greenMultiplier=0, blueMultiplier=0, alphaMultiplier=1, redOffset=0, greenOffset=102, blueOffset=51, alphaOffset=0)'

var obj = {};

str.replace(/(\w+)=(\d+)/g, function (match, $1, $2){ 
    obj[$1] = parseInt($2);
});

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to convert into `array`

```
var str = "(redMultiplier=0, greenMultiplier=0, blueMultiplier=0, alphaMultiplier=1, redOffset=0, greenOffset=102, blueOffset=51, alphaOffset=0)".replace(/[()]/g, '');
console.log(str.split(','));
var newArr = str.split(',');
var finalArr = [];
newArr.map((elem) => {
    finalArr.push( elem.replace('=', ':') );
});

console.log(finalArr);
```